# is there any python module to submit job in sun engine queuing system

Tags: python, grid, sun

I am working on running shell script in sun engine grid system using "qsub" command. I want to do similar thing using python. So instead of calling qsub directly from command prompt. I need a python module which help me to submit jobs in sub engine grid. I also want to check there execution status like we do with "qstat" command. Is there any python module to do the same?

Comment: Give this a try: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html, this allows you to run commands like `qsub` and `qstat` via python on command line!

Comment: thanks Devesh, but i need a wrapper function which directly call sun engine grid instead of subprocess which works as a command line tool again :)